# Unable to do a nested loop with Ansible

Tags: yaml, ansible

I am trying to set up a playbook that loops over some sites.  Within the sites, there will be routers and switches.  Generally there will be 1 router and at least 1 switch.  For now, I am just trying to get the logic to work for both sites, 1 router each.  I believe I need to "with_nested" but can't come up with the winning code.  This is what I have now:

```
hosts: local

vars:
  data_vlan: 10
  voice_vlan: 20

  sites:
    - site1:
      routers:
        - hostname: router1
          loopback0: 192.168.1.1
          wan_ip: 10.0.0.2
          lan_ip: 172.16.1.1

    - site2:
      routers:
        - hostname: router1
          loopback0: 192.168.2.1
          wan_ip: 10.0.0.4
          lan_ip: 172.16.2.1

tasks:

  - name: Generate router configs
    template: src=templates/router.j2 dest=scripts/{{ item  [1] }}/{{ item[1] }}-{{ item[1] }}.txt
    with_nested:
      - "{{ sites }}"
```

For now I have item[1] that third time in the dest section, but eventually i want that to be hostname.  So scripts/site1/site1-router1.txt and so on.  With that code, it gets site1 and site2 correct, but I can't figure out how to get to the hostname vars.

I've tried multiple variables under with_nested but just can't get it.  Final result would be:

site1, router 1

site1, switch 1

site1, switch N

site2, router 1

site2, switch 1

site2, switch N

Answer (score 1):

First, there either is a conceptual problem in your YAML or maybe it got broken when indenting the code here on stackoverflow.

Excerpt:

```
  sites:
    - site1:
      routers:
        - hostname: router1
```

IMHO that does not make sense. `site1` is an empty key. It should either be one of these options:

1. `routers` should be a subelement of site1:

   ```
     sites:
       - site1:
           routers:
             - hostname: router1
   ```
2. Sites should be a dict instead of a list:

   ```
     sites:
       site1:
         routers:
           - hostname: router1
   ```
3. The site name should be stored as a value, not as a key:

   ```
     sites:
       - name: site1
         routers:
           - hostname: router1
   ```

Let's pick option 3, since it is the easiest to loop over. Also it does not require you to know the name of the site to access the content. All content can be accessed by general keys (`sites[0].name` / `sites[0].routers[0].hostname` etc) In all other solutions you would be required to know the name of the site before you can access the content.

> I believe I need to "with_nested"

Close. I also get them always wrong and have to look it up. The correct loop to use would be [with_subelements](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html):

```
- debug: msg="{{ item.0.name }} {{ item.1.hostname }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ sites }}"
    - routers
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that.  I initially had things structured how you have it in option 3 but tried so many things it got bastardized.  Now onto figuring out the Jinja2 part.